# Resize icon in dojox.mobile.ListItem

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I've some code to create item to add listitem dojo in my worklight app:

```
  var n = domConstruct.create("div", {innerHTML:     
                            "<div class='pName'><h4>"+hotDeal[i].title+"</h4></div>" +
                            "<div class='pNumber'>"+hotDeal[i].desc+"</div>"+
                            '<a href="'+hotDeal[i].url+'">Read more</a>'+
                            "</div>"});
                        var icon = hotDeal[i].img;      

                                 var policyInit = {icon:icon};
                                 policyInit["class"] = "mblVariableHeight";
                                var policyItem = new dojox.mobile.ListItem(policyInit,n);
                                viewWishlist.addChild(policyItem);
```

My problem is icon of item is too big ( **hotDeal[i].img** is image url),i want to resize icon of item in listitem dojox mobile.How i can do that ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resize manually the image in the images folder

Comment: that image url.i can't resize it.

Comment: override the css class ".mblImageIcon" and set width and height (is the default class for this element )

Comment: Oh,I want ask some more,i've override that css class and it resize all my icon item (both icon menu).How i can resize only icon of listitem ?

Comment: I've found this .mblListItemIcon, override this class ,every thing is ok :D